# The growth on my cacti has changed, and it wierd

Tags: identification, diagnosis, diseases, growth, cactus

I asked a question about the growth on my cacti earlier in the summer, however it's just acting weird. I initially thought it was a cacti fruit because it originated from a flower I tried to cross pollinate. But it's looking strange to me, and I'm not really sure what my cacti is doing?! [image: This is the growth from a few weeks ago][image: This is my cacti today]

Comment: It is a flower.

Comment: It is NOT a flower, the flower on my cacti are pink and very clearly flowers. This is something else

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a [pup](https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/ornamental/cacti-succulents/scgen/removing-cactus-pups.htm) and I've seen quite a few of my cacti do this. It's inevitable for branching types as they'd have no means of growing otherwise and I haven't seen it on barrel types like this one, but I can't imagine there is any cause for concern. It's possible it's doing it in reaction to an injury - did you accidentally rip off an areole? - or some balance of nutrients, light, moisture etc it wouldn't see in nature.

You could probably snap or cut it off once it's grown a bit more and grow a clone, if you wanted.

Comment: Thank you! That makes a lot of sense. I didnt rip of an aeiole, I was actually trying my pollinate some of the flowers my cacti had haha. So I guess this is what happenes

Answer (score 1):

This is an offset or a new branch. The plant looks like a Mammillaria of some description.

These don't always show up in the most aesthetically pleasing locations as you can see. Removing them allows you to root them and have another plant. Unfortunately, the distortion from producing the offset and the scar will permanently mark the plant.

I would leave it alone, personally.

Comment: Thank you! That's a cool concept that I didnt really think of. I find it a little strange that my cacti is doing that because I didnt think these kinds did that, but it probably is a hybrid anyway. Thank you for your help

Comment: Some Mammillaria offset profusely to create large mounds of stems. Offsetting is generally a sign of health/vigor, unless the main growing point is dead or damaged.